# How to disable password on Hibernate/Suspend?

Tags: 11.10, password, suspend, hibernate

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 and on suspend/hibernate I am asked for password. I couldn't find `apps > gnome-power-manager > lock` in gconf-editor. What's the solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'`

It disables the locking altogether.

Comment: Intuitive. How come 90% of Ubuntu home PC users didn't upvote this? I do this six years later on 17.10.

Answer (score 0):

System settings > Screen > Screen Lock > off
if I'm getting it right.

Comment: doesn't work :( already did it.

Comment: I think this is a bug [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/871560)