# Turn off requesting user password after suspend 17.10

Tags: suspend, password, 17.10, lock-screen, auto-login

I enabled automatic login on my mother's laptop so that she wouldn't have to require a password to login. In previous versions of Ubuntu you used to be able to configure a specific setting in gnome-tweak-tool to toggle if you wanted the user to require to enter their password to log in after a suspend/hibernate. The only option I can find for this is to disable the lock-screen completely, which I don't want since sometimes she might want to lock the screen when walking away from the laptop. Setting `Privacy > Screen Lock` to off doesn't affect this behaviour.

How can this be done with Ubuntu 17.10?

- Automatic login on boot
- Screen lock still enabled
- Don't require password after resuming from suspend/hibernate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. For me solution was this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend 'false'
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it! I reported a bug at LP: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1740792

Comment: By the way [it is the same answer as in 2011](https://askubuntu.com/a/68395/577717) (upvote that too!).